# How do I list added files between tags in a specific directory?

Tags: git

I have no idea where to start here so I haven't tried anything yet. Basically I want to get all tags (which are version numbers) sorted from most recent to oldest and generate a list of added files in a specific directory from one tag to the next. The files themselves are small markdown snippets and I'd like to put them all into one file with a heading for each tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git tag` lists all tags, but not in "version order"; you'll have to do your "version number sort" some other way.  This can be arbitrarily hard since the marketing-and-sales people like to make sure no one can understand which version is which, so as to force customers to buy more versions. :-)

Assuming you have a list you can step through pairwise, e.g., something like:

```
versions="v0.01 v0.02 v1 v1.1alpha v1.1 v1.1a v3 \
   vmarketing-name vdifferent-name \
   v2.1-because-marketing-thinks-2-greater-than-3"
```

you can then do something like this (in sh / bash):

```
set -- $versions
prev=$1
shift
for tag in $versions; do
    echo "$prev => $tag"
    git diff $prev $tag --diff-filter=A --name-only -- this/dir
    echo "----------------------------------"
done
```

How this works:

- `git diff` gets you the changes from one commit to another.
- the commits to be compared are the "previous tag" `$prev` and "this tag" `$tag`
- we tell `git diff` to look only at path `this/dir`
- we tell `git diff` to filter out changes other than `A`dded-files
- we tell `git diff` to print only the file names

(and then the echo adds a cut-line in case the changes are extensive or empty).

Comment: You're a git god @torek!

Comment: FYI here's the site that my eventual script pumped out using Flatdoc: http://mergext.com/notes.html